# Where to go with "opinion based" questions?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about programming languages that is opinion-based. [I put it in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420677/where-to-go-from-php), where it was quickly closed. I tried to find another StackExchange site, but cannot find one.

I understand that these questions do not belong in StackOverflow, but where to go to with them? Many opinion-based questions are interesting and many people can learn valuable things from other people's opinions and tips.

Comment: Not on **any** current SE site. But the internet is a big place...

Comment: @juergend thanks. Is that a deliberate choice, or the site just didn't pop up yet?

Comment: reddit/r/programming, quora, a relevant linkedIn group, slant.co (for comparison questions).

Comment: @BartFriederichs It's a deliberate choice. Nothing inherently wrong with opinion based questions, they just don't fit SE's philosophy and platform. Q&A (and voting) works best with specific questions, and it quickly falls apart with broad / opinion based questions.

Comment: Put it this way: Stack Exchange is as suited to opinion-based questions as a restaurant is for buying toys.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn [cracker barrel](http://www.crackerbarrel.com/) you'd be amazed

Comment: Scratch that. Stack Exchange is as suitable for opinion-based questions as land is for marine life.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Or maybe: StackExchange is as suitable for opinion-based questions as deserts are for fish.

Comment: You might find this valuable: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8401)